# XCode4 Project to makefile

Tags: xcode, makefile

Does anyone know of a tool that takes an EXSISTING xcode project and converts it into a makefile? [PBTOMAKE](http://members.bellatlantic.net/~vze35xda/software.html) is only for Xcode2.

Comment: why not just drop `xcodebuild` into a makefile and build your project that way?  :-)

Comment: It might be that with the workspaces and schemes introduced in the later versions of xcode, such a tool is more challenging to develop.

Comment: To what end? Do you want to build at the command line (use xcodebuild) or do you want to port to an other Unix OS?

Comment: I want to port to another Unix OS